# Bootstrap data-toggle breaks ng-show and vice versa

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-show

I have a form switcher using two radio buttons:

```
                <form>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label class="btn btn-info">
                                <input type="radio" name="formSwitcher" id="gNr" ng-model="vm.formSwitcher" value="gNr" /> Form for new G
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="radio">
                            <label class="btn btn-info">
                                <input type="radio" name="formSwitcher" id="pNr" ng-model="vm.formSwitcher" value="pNr" /> Form for new P
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

<div ng-show="vm.formSwitcher == 'gNr' ">
   <form> ... </form>
</div>

<div ng-show="vm.formSwitcher == 'pNr' ">
   <form> ... </form>
</div>
```

This is working as expected, I choose a radio button and the appropriate forms show/hide accordingly.

When I add `data-toggle="buttons"` to the 2nd line above, `<div class="btn-group">`, the `ng-hide` stops working BUT the change in visual state (appearing pressed or unpressed) works fine.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
```

When I remove the `data-toggle` I don't get the variation in button color to show which of the radios is selected (the radio black dot still appears correctly).

Why would `data-toggle="buttons"` stop `ng-show` from working? The customer wants to see the button/radio change color on select.

Comment: If you dont mean, construct jsfiddle for the question

Comment: Not necessary to use jsFiddle here, I think this is simple enough without. The radio button behaviour can be seen here for those unfamiliar: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio  and anyone answering this should already be familiar with ng-show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra `<div class="radio">`.

Remove them and it should work like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iMarti/dm94719f/).

Comment: Thank you, your fiddle didn't work on my project, but it did provide the answer, by removing 'data-toggle="buttons"' and adding 'ng-class="{active: vm.formSwitcher=='gNr'}"' to the labels (with the -extra- div class=radio in place) I was able to get what was required. Thanks, I'll mark you as _the answer_ because your fiddle works, just some other factor in my project stopped it working for me :)

Comment: It's probably a difference in Bootstrap or Angular versions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was jQuery.

1. When including bootstrap.min.js it wanted to include jQuery. You can remove bootstrap.min.js & jQuery in which just put an `ng-class` on the label to set the active state.

Reference Mart's fiddle from above for `ng-class` examples.

2. If removing jQuery is not an option for you:
   The other option is in the comments above saying just to remove the data-toggle. From there you can throw a `style="display:none"` directly on your radio inputs or create a class in your style sheet.