# Bootstrap data-toggle breaking Angular ng-show

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

As the title says, When creating a bootstrap radio button group the data-toggle="buttons" attribute is causing the Angular ng-show function to be disabled or break.

I have read the following stackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021872/bootstrap-data-toggle-breaks-ng-show-and-vice-versa). In the selected answer @Mart has said using

```
ng-class="{active: vm.formSwitcher=='pNr'}"
```

fixes the problem but if you copy the code from his [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iMarti/dm94719f/) and use the latest version of AngularJS (not version 1.2 like JSFiddle uses) it does not work. Is there a new fix for this issue?

I am using:

```
AngularJS version: 1.4.3  
Bootstrap version: 3.3.5
JQuery version:    2.1.4
```

Comment: Have you tried UI Bootstrap? http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons

Comment: Thanks a load I was using it for my accordions but I didnt even think to look for radio buttons. Man I feel stupid. If you would like you can post that as an answer and Ill accept.